# Responsive image stuttering in Next.js ver.13

Tags: image

I intended to change the logo image at a certain size for responsive work. As a result, the image has changed well. But there is one problem. The first or two attempts to change the image caused a stuttering(Stuttering in which the image instantly grows and becomes smaller and expressed as intended) problem. After the first or two stumbles, the stuttering disappears. Only stumbles the first time or two. The following is the code I wrote. Please help me with how I can solve it.

(The logo image is not downloaded from the server, i worked in a local environment, so it is never a server problem.)

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function SidebarLogo({ desktopWidth }: Pick<SidebarProps, "desktopWidth">) {
  return (
    <>
      <figure className={`${desktopWidth === true ? "mt-8 mb-10" : "mt-8 mb-11"}`}>
        <Image
          src={`/sidebar/desktop/${desktopWidth === true ? "desktop_logo" : "tablet_logo"}.svg`}
          alt="logo"
          width={`${desktopWidth === true ? 140 : 50}`}
          height={`${desktopWidth === true ? 42 : 60}`}
          className="mx-auto"
        />
      </figure>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried searching to solve this problem, but I couldn't try anything else because I couldn't find any information related to the problem because there was a lack of search methods. I want the logo image to be changed without stuttering.